# How to fix the Hibernate “object references an unsaved" when a pojo has two entities same table in a many-to-one relation

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistence

I have a parent A table that has a one-to-many relationship with a table B.
In the file generated with Hibernate 3.6 version.

```
public class A {
private B firstChild;
private B secondChild;

When i save myParent "a":

firstObject = a.getFirstChild();
session.saveOrUpdate(firstObject);
session.saverOrUpdate(a);
```

i have Exception:
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

In my Parent POJO I have two instances of same Table (second record have a column with ID_relation value equal ID primary first record)
example

```
a = Progressive ID 178, Name,  Surname, FK with B and ID_B ="1"
B first = ID sequence 1, Description , Price , ID REL null
B second = ID sequence 6, Description ,Price, ID REL ="1"
```

Thanks

Comment: Show how have you defined relations.

Comment: Try having `CascadeType.ALL` or saving the two B entities before saving the A entitiy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix the Hibernate "object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/how-to-fix-the-hibernate-object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23606953/573032

Comment: Hi, while debuggin I founded "org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved" in my class Parent A I have a Pojo maps a Table with a FK ,  <many-to-one name="Addresses" class="mypackage.Addresses" fetch="select" update="false" insert="false" >
            <column name="ID_Address"  />
        </many-to-one>  If I don't insert a record Address i have the error

Comment: Examples about map a single table to multiple classes are all refer Hibernate version 5, i am using older version 3.6 thanks a lots

Comment: Solved :-) I have another entity in class A which was an instance (class D has a relation with A with pk and fk) with all properties null. I must pass this entity with null so Hibernate works perfectly. So I don't want insert a record in D table and with Hibernate the entinty must be NULL. bye